# How do you rename files ignoring file extension in terminal?

Tags: scripts, filename

I have several folders of video files that need to be renamed to something uniform, eg: `foldername.videotypexvideonumber.avi`. I have looked at creating a shell script to make this easier. The `mv` command seems to be the best way to do this.

However, every guide/tutorial/manpage I've seen says that when I rename a file I have to also include the file extension. This would normally be fine, but some folders have videos of multiple file types, eg .mkv and .avi and even some .rmvb files.

So, what I need to know is if there's a way to rename files through the terminal **without** having to specify the file type when doing so - basically so that the extension stays the same, regardless of what it is before renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

You can't do that since extensions are part of filename.

**Long answer:**

You can use a graphical interface to do advanced renames as `purrr` or `gprename`

### BUT!

In your batch renaming script you can use the following techniques of filename splitting:

```
FULLFILENAME="/home/user/video/myvideo-release.xvid.128kbps.avi"
DIRNAME=$(dirname ${FULLFILENAME})   #-- /home/user/video
BASENAME=$(basename ${FULLFILENAME}) #-- myvideo-release.xvid.128kbps.avi
FILENAME=${BASENAME%.*}              #-- myvideo-release.xvid.128kbps
EXTENSION=${BASENAME##*.}            #-- avi
```

Comment: I don't really understand what is said at the beginning. Obviously, anything you can do in a script you can do in a shell...

Comment: Nice one, thanks a lot. That should make my life easier.

Comment: Also, you probably want things like `FILENAME="${BASENAME%.*}"` with the quotes in case the filenames have spaces in them.

Comment: I have edited a bit to clarify the point.

Comment: Why are you using `basename` and `dirname` when you already know how to use parameter expansion? Also, you failed to quote the arguments to `basename` and `dirname`, so if someone tries your solution, they'll get problems with filenames containing special characters. And lastly, the convention is to use lower case variable names for everything but environment variables. Please see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know *exactly* what you want to do, but you can certainly do this. Learning about [BASH parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) is probably pretty necessary.

Depending on what you what to do, you may need to separate the extension and the filename, or maybe not.

I'm going to suppose you've already `cd`ed into the folder with the files in question.

**case 1:** suppose you want to change the string "bad" to "good" in every file name; then you can use a simple substitution, i.e., you can do something like:

`for file in * ; do mv "$file" "${file//bad/good}" ; done`

(Do make sure that there is no change that changing bad to good will overwrite something already there.) That'll work regardless of extension.

**case 2:** Suppse you need to add "new" before the extension, whatever it is, then you can do:

`for file in * ; do filename="${file%.*}" ; extension="${file##*.}" ; mv "$file" "${filename}new.${extension}" ; done`

The extension will remain the same, whatever it was.

I'd give more advice, but again, I really don't know what you're trying to do, exactly.

Comment: In terms of _exactly_ what I want to do: I want to batch rename files from (for example) `[DB]_2437968_Bleach_298.avi` to `Bleach.09x12.avi` - that would be no problem if every file had the same extension. I want to change the file name _only_ before the extension.

Comment: Where does the `09x12` come from, and how do you determine what part of the old filename to use, e.g. how would you know to use `Bleach` in this case?

Comment: Indeed; you can certainly do this, but we need to know the exact rules for how to transform the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
[temp] λ = ls
test.doc  test.rtf  test.txt
[temp] λ = for f in *; do mv "$f" test2`echo "$f" | sed 's/[^.]*//'`; done
[temp] λ = ls
test2.doc  test2.rtf  test2.txt
```

There might be a more elegant way to do it but it works

Replace **test2** with anything you want a counter or something.